# alter the data type of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I need to alter the data type of a column in one table of mine, but this table contains data my problem is that I can't empty the table to do my purpose so I need to Alter the column data type without emptying the table.

What can I do ?

Comment: Would you please describe the original and the target column type?

Comment: Modify the data to meet the needs of the target data type, then alter the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best choice here is to create a new table `new_table` with the appropriate columns.

Once created, insert into this table the values of the existing table `table` as you want them. Only then reintroduce constraints etc (if you do this before insert, you'll penalize insert performance).

Once done, rename `table` to `old_table` and `new_table` to `table`.

Of course, you need to do this with your application offline.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Alter Table

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name column_type;
```

The data type of text, ntext and image columns can be changed only in the following ways:

- `text` to `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, or `xml`
- `ntext` to `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, or `xml`
- `image` to `varbinary(max)`

For other conversions you will have to do casting. Refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for casting

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY ...` is not valid SQL Server syntax.

Comment: It would have to be `ALTER TABLE (table_name) ALTER COLUMN (column_name) .....` to be valid for SQL Server